# Animation not working despite the class is added

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add my beating animation only to the text between arrows (arrows shouldn't have beating).

But unfortunately I'm unable to find the reason why the animation is not working (the heart class which contains the animation is added to the container of text but no animation is visible).

How can I fix this?

```js
setTimeout(() => prepareLabelShow("This is the caption"), 2500);
const prepareLabel = document.querySelector(".prepareLabel");
function prepareLabelShow(text, state) {

    function startBeating() {
        const prepareLabelGroup = document.getElementById("prepare-label-group");
        prepareLabelGroup.classList.add("heart");
    }

    prepareLabel.innerHTML = `<span class="right-arrow arrow">&#8249;</span><div style="display:inline" id="prepare-label-group">${text}</div><span class="left-arrow arrow">&#8250;</span>`;
    startBeating();
    prepareLabel.classList.add("prepareLabelShow");
    prepareLabel.classList.remove("prepareLabelHide");

} // end of prepareLabelShow function
```

```css
.prepare-label-container {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
  top: 68.5vh; 
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.prepareLabel {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Vazir";
    direction: rtl;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #f8f7fa;
    opacity: 0;  
    margin: 0 auto;
   
}
.prepareLabelShow {
    animation: prepareLabelAnimeShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes prepareLabelAnimeShow {
  0%    { opacity: 0; top: 4vh }
  100%  { opacity: 1; top: 1.2vh }
}

.heart {
  animation: beat .5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes beat {
  0%   { opacity:1; transform: scale(1); }
  100% { opacity:1; transform: scale(0.8); }
}

.arrow {
  /*color: #e9e1f2;
  font-size: 1.2vw;*/

  color: #ff9900;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}

.left-arrow {
  padding-right: 7vw;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.right-arrow {
  padding-left: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<div class ="prepare-label-container">
        <p class="prepareLabel"></p>
    </div>
```

I did not simplified the code in purpose.

The desired result is to see the beating animation in the text inside two arrows.

Comment: This is one of those ones where providing a jsfiddle or something would really help in trying to figure out whats going in ‍♂️

Comment: Of course: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/PoGQBmN

Comment: Not seeing a `prepare-label-group` in your html. Do see it in your js. Likely the console dev tools would have alerted you to this discrepancy.

Comment: Yes but I'm adding the beating after innerHTML

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Does your `heart` class work independently of javascript? What I mean is what happens if you explicitly (as in inline) specify this class on the element?

Comment: I think it's because there is another animation for this element at the first place then when I want to add another one the error happens... I just guess!!!

Comment: There not such `prepare-label-group` element in the DOM I just add it dynamically via javascript

Comment: Guys if you add the `heart` animation to the container it works fine ... but I don't want to animate the arrows...

Comment: Well looking at your code again Sara Ree, `startBeating()` seems pointless. Have you tried just simply adding the class inline to your inner div? What happens when you do that?

Comment: Added the `heart` inline still not working. I want the function to dynamically start and stop beating ... it's not pointless I think...

Comment: Using inline-block instead of inline solved the issue... WHy?

Comment: By "inline" I meant to type the `class="heart"` directly on the element. But you may have hit the nail on something in that css animations can only be applied to "block" level elements. Worth looking into.